# Return a path relative to the site root, not server root

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

### Why?

I need to detect whether a given path contains the directory `app` but only after the root of the site (i.e. ignore the full server path, only search the paths within the actual site).

Consider the following paths:

- `/root/var/www/app/app/Http` **true**
- `/root/var/www/app/public` **false**
- `C:\Users\john\Sites\example_com\www\app\Http` **true**

### What I have tried...

I have solved the above using the following code:

```
// Normalise the directory separators in the document
// root
$document_root = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

// Remove the '/public' path from the end, this should 
// give us the path to the site root...
$site_root = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public', '', $document_root);

// Normalise the directory separators in the supplied
// path
$normalised_path = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path['path']);

// Remove the site root from the beginning of the path
$stripped_path = str_replace($site_root, '', $normalised_path);

// Now we can run our tests...
```

### My Question

Is it just me or does the above code seem ridiculous for such a simple task? Can anyone suggest a better, or cleaner, way of achieving this? Essentially, I am trying to strip the server root from a given path in order to give me a path relative to the site root...

If there is a way to achieve this using built in classes/methods in Laravel/Lumen then please feel free to suggest these too.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Shouldn't the third example you posted not match (as there's no `app` below the `www/app`)?

Comment: @atymic - This is a poor example from my part, the `www` is the site root in that example, so the directory `app` is within the site root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to do something like this:

The `app_path` helper will return the path of the `app` (ie, your application code)

```php
Str::contains('/root/var/www/app/app/Http', app_path()); // true
Str::contains('/root/var/www/app/public', app_path()); // false
Str::contains('C:\Users\john\Sites\example_com\www\app\Http', app_path()); // true
```

Helper Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-app-path

Comment: Exactly the sort of simple built in solution I was looking for! Thank you